# Why are these errors appearing with if and else functions

Tags: python, if-statement

Just started Python programming and I am currently learning about the if, else and elif functions from an online course i bought. I did everything word for word but i keep getting errors on VSC. The course is using different software, so maybe it has something to do with the program difference. Here is the code. Thanks in advance.

```
print("Hello and welcome to the roller coaster!")

height = float(input("Let's start with your height! Please type in your height in m "))


if height >= 1.3:
   age = input("You are allowed to ride the roller coaster! Now, how old are you?")

if  int(input("age")) < 12:
    print("Your total is $5")
elif  int(input("age")) < 18:
    print("Your total is $7")
else:
    print("Your total is $12")
else:
    print("I'm sorry but you are too short to ride the roller coaster. Come back later.")
```

I tried looking it up here but couldn't find a solution. here are the error messages

[{

```
"severity": 8,
"message": "Expected expression",
"source": "Pylance",
"startLineNumber": 15,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 15,
"endColumn": 5
```

}]

[{
"severity": 8,
"message": "Unexpected indentation",
"source": "Pylance",
"startLineNumber": 16,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 16,
"endColumn": 5
}]

[{

```
"severity": 8,
"message": "Unindent not expected",
"source": "Pylance",
"startLineNumber": 16,
"startColumn": 90,
"endLineNumber": 16,
"endColumn": 90
```

}]

[{

```
"severity": 8,
"message": "Expected expression",
"source": "Pylance",
"startLineNumber": 16,
"startColumn": 90,
"endLineNumber": 16,
"endColumn": 90
```

}]

[{

```
"severity": 8,
"message": "Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons",
"source": "Pylance",
"startLineNumber": 16,
"startColumn": 90,
"endLineNumber": 16,
"endColumn": 90
```

}]

Comment: You second if block should be indented.

Comment: furthermore your are requesting the `age` input twice ...

Comment: Just as asimoneau said. Python depends on indentation. Your last "else" looks wrongly indented. See [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_if_nested.asp)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to note:

- As indicated in the comments there is an issue with the indentation of the second "if/else" block.
- And, there is a second unnecessary request for age.

With that in mind, following is a refactored version of your program with some bits simplified.

```
print("Hello and welcome to the roller coaster!")

height = float(input("Let's start with your height! Please type in your height in m "))

if height >= 1.3:
    age = input("You are allowed to ride the roller coaster! Now, how old are you? ")

    if  int(age) < 12:              # This block of code needed to be indented
        print("Your total is $5")
    elif  int(age) < 18:            # Changed to just a simple value test - no need to input age a second time
        print("Your total is $7")
    else:
        print("Your total is $12")
else:
    print("I'm sorry but you are too short to ride the roller coaster. Come back later.")
```

Note the refinement of the age testing.

Following are a couple of tests for height and age.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Coaster$ python3 Coaster.py 
Hello and welcome to the roller coaster!
Let's start with your height! Please type in your height in m 1.2
I'm sorry but you are too short to ride the roller coaster. Come back later.
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Coaster$ python3 Coaster.py 
Hello and welcome to the roller coaster!
Let's start with your height! Please type in your height in m 1.4
You are allowed to ride the roller coaster! Now, how old are you? 15
Your total is $7
```

The takeaway here is always be cognizant of proper indentation with your "if/else" testing as well as any structures you might use (e.g. "while loops", and so forth).

Comment: aight thanks worked out great i understand what I did wrong now

Answer (score 0):

Indentation often gets many layers deep. In your case you will need two layers of indentations because you have two layers of `if` blocks (an `if` inside an `if`):

```
print("Hello and welcome to the roller coaster!")

height = float(input("Let's start with your height! Please type in your height in m "))


if height >= 1.3:
   age = input("You are allowed to ride the roller coaster! Now, how old are you?")

    if  int(input("age")) < 12:
        print("Your total is $5")
    elif  int(input("age")) < 18:
        print("Your total is $7")
    else:
        print("Your total is $12")
else:
    print("I'm sorry but you are too short")
```

Comment: Need to fix multiple calls to `input("age")`.